# Error: _AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 4893 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.)

Tags: flutter, dart

I face a problem about `_AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 4893 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.)`. I've been looking for a way to fix this for a long time, but I still can't find a solution.

[image: Error picture]

I would be very grateful for any user help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add this to your code:

```dart
Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
  Navigator.pop(context);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```dart
Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 10), () {
  Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
});
```